# Does Snowflake create a Temp Table for CTEs?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

I am analyzing some stock data using the following query to average the closing price on monthly basis:

```
// use ZEPL_STOCKS;
with MONTHLY_AVERAGES AS
(SELECT DISTINCT
  SYMBOL
  , YEAR(DATE) as YEAR
  , month(DATE) as MONTH
  , avg(close) over(partition by symbol, year(DATE), month(DATE)) as MONTHLY_CLOSE_AVG 
  , avg(adjclose) over(partition by symbol, year(DATE), month(DATE)) as MONTHLY_ADJCLOSE_AVG 
  , avg(open) over(partition by symbol, year(DATE), month(DATE)) as MONTHLY_OPEN_AVG 
  , avg(high) over(partition by symbol, year(DATE), month(DATE)) as MONTHLY_HIGH_AVG
  , avg(low) over(partition by symbol, year(DATE), month(DATE)) as MONTHLY_LOW_AVG 
  , avg(volume) over(partition by symbol, year(DATE), month(DATE)) as MONTHLY_VOLUME_AVG 
 
from 
STOCK_HISTORY)
select 
  M_AVG_2020.SYMBOL
  , M_AVG_2020.MONTH
  , M_AVG_2020.MONTHLY_CLOSE_AVG CLOSE_AVG_2020 
  , M_AVG_2021.MONTHLY_CLOSE_AVG CLOSE_AVG_2021
  , M_AVG_2022.MONTHLY_CLOSE_AVG CLOSE_AVG_2022
  FROM MONTHLY_AVERAGES as M_AVG_2020
inner join MONTHLY_AVERAGES as M_AVG_2021
  on M_AVG_2020.SYMBOL=M_AVG_2021.SYMBOL AND M_AVG_2020.MONTH=M_AVG_2021.MONTH
inner join MONTHLY_AVERAGES as M_AVG_2022
  on M_AVG_2020.SYMBOL=M_AVG_2022.SYMBOL AND M_AVG_2020.MONTH=M_AVG_2022.MONTH
where M_AVG_2020.YEAR=2020 and M_AVG_2021.YEAR=2021 and M_AVG_2022.YEAR=2022 --and M_AVG_2020.SYMBOL='ORCL'
ORDER BY SYMBOL, MONTH;
```

While this query works, it is very slow when more years are analyzed or a finer time grain is used. What is the best way to optimize this query?

here is the query plan:
[image]

Comment: Start by understanding the query plan https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/explain.html . Post the query plan here and someone may be able to help

Answer (score 0):

This is slow because you are doing Window functions and distinct, change to group by

```
(SELECT
  SYMBOL
  , YEAR(DATE) as YEAR
  , month(DATE) as MONTH
  , avg(close) as MONTHLY_CLOSE_AVG 
  , avg(adjclose) as MONTHLY_ADJCLOSE_AVG 
  , avg(open) as MONTHLY_OPEN_AVG 
  , avg(high) as MONTHLY_HIGH_AVG
  , avg(low) as MONTHLY_LOW_AVG 
  , avg(volume) as MONTHLY_VOLUME_AVG 
from STOCK_HISTORY
Group by 1,2,3
)
```

I would be inclined to move the WHERE clauses onto the JOIN ON's and push a filter into the CTE:

```
with MONTHLY_AVERAGES AS (
    SELECT 
      symbol
      ,YEAR(DATE) as year
      ,month(DATE) as month
      ,avg(close) as monthly_close_avg 
      ,avg(adjclose) as monthly_adjclose_avg 
      ,avg(open) as monthly_open_avg 
      ,avg(high) as monthly_high_avg
      ,avg(low) as monthly_low_avg 
      ,avg(volume) as monthly_volume_avg 
    from stock_history
    where DATE >= '2020-01-01'::date
    group by 1,2,3
)
select 
  m_avg_2020.symbol
  ,m_avg_2020.month
  ,m_avg_2020.monthly_close_avg as close_avg_2020 
  ,m_avg_2021.monthly_close_avg as close_avg_2021
  ,m_avg_2022.monthly_close_avg as close_avg_2022
FROM monthly_averages AS m_avg_2020
join monthly_averages as m_avg_2021
    on m_avg_2020.symbol = m_avg_2021.symbol 
        and m_avg_2020.month = m_avg_2021.month
        and m_avg_2020.year = 2020
        and m_avg_2021.year = 2021 
        -- m_avg_2020.symbol='orcl'
join monthly_averages as as m_avg_2022
    on m_avg_2020.symbol = m_avg_2022.symbol 
        and m_avg_2020.month = m_avg_2022.month
        and m_avg_2022.year = 2022
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Comment: Also, you may be able to achieve what you want using PIVOT rather than all those joins. If you can update your question with the result you want to achieve it would help to see if PIVOT would be an option

Comment: I find pivot slow and more cumbersome to use verse just hand rolling it.